# Django periodic task celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm a newbie in Django and Celery.
Help me please, I can't understand, how it work. I want to see in my console "Hello world" every 1 min.

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute=1)), ignore_result=True)
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test.settings.local")

app = Celery('test')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

celeryconfig.py

```
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379'
result_backend = 'rpc://'

task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'Europe/Oslo'
enable_utc = True
```

It's a simple celery settings and code, but doesn't worked =\

```
celery -A tasks worker -B
```

And nothing happens. Tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi ferOm! `crontab(hour="*", minute=1)` will run your task once every hour (on the first minute). You could probably use `crontab(hour="*", minute='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,59')` to schedule it every minute, but that's not very nice. Maybe use `@app.on_after_configure.connect` instead? See the docs: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup beat_schedule in your celeryconfig.py

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
beat_schedule = {
    'send_each_minute': {
        'task': 'your.module.path.function',
        'schedule': crontab(),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```